# How to save/revert changes to only parts of a buffer?

Tags: buffers, ediff, diff, saving, revert-buffer

I'd love a partial `save-buffer` and/or `revert-buffer` (if I have one, I think I could easily enough implement the other). Perhaps where I select a region and have only changes within that region get saved.

Basically, something abstractly similar to `git (add|reset|checkout|stash) -p` (or like Magit's ability to really precisely stage/unstage/discard/stash changes), but for *saving from buffer to file* rather than from file to version control.

I would find this helpful for the same reasons that I find those things helpful in Git: it would reduce coupling between all the changes I have in-progress and the changes I am ready to promote to the next stage of testing/done-ness. I can be making one change, think of another change along the way, and now I have two changes in-flight in the buffer - once I finish one of those changes, it would be great if I could save the finished change to file on disk while holding back the drafted unfinished changes. This would be great to have at the level of my editor because then it composes with any use-case and tool.

(I would also accept an answer which provides enough of the same workflow wins - for example, if I had to build my own solution, currently the best I can come up with which actually seems doable reasonably quickly is to write a function which creates a temporary buffer with a copy of the current contents, reverts the current buffer, and then pops open a diff between the two buffers, and then I would look at existing Emacs diff and ediff functionality, and however Magit is implemented, for how to add some sort of key bindings to at least apply individual diff hunks from the temp buffer to the original buffer. Even being able to apply diff hunks directly from an editable `diff-buffer-with-file` diff buffer to the underlying file would be a decent 80+% solution.)

Comment: (I have just started closely looking into Ediff, in particular `ediff-current-file` seems promising, as something that might be very close to what I want.)